# Is there a way to forward declare a namespace or just make it visible in advance?

Tags: c++

I'm doing online programming tests like leetcode, **which requires only one .cpp file, so I have to place everything into one .cpp file.**

And I used to write `main()` function ahead of any other functions, but that way I have to forward declare every function I use, which is very annoying. So I think of something like the snippet below:

```
 namespace function;//oop,there is no such forward declaration
    int main()
    {
      using namespace function;//compiler could not find this actually;
      f1();
      ...
    }
    namespace function
    {
      f1(){...};
      f2(){...};
      ...
    }
```

But the compiler complains, since there is no forward declaration of namespaces (unlike functions), which makes the namespace invisible to the compiler.

**Is there any way to forward declare a namespace?** Just like

```
void f1();
int main()
{
 f1();//ok,because there is a forward declaration
}
void f1()
{ ...}
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `main` at the end?

Comment: @nwp Possible personal habit,but I think it's better to put it at front,because this could make the code more readable,since i don't need to scroll down the page to see what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not having to forward declare functions is the most important goal, you can abuse the fact that a class also defines a namespace scope where you don't have to forward declare member functions.

Something like this:

```
struct program
{

    int main()
    {
      f1();
      f2();

      return  0;
    }

    void f1(){}
    void f2(){}

};

// The real main still needed here

int main()
{ return program{}.main(); }
```

Technically this works, but still not really recommended.

Comment: Cool,but a little weird indeed.

Comment: Very neat abuse. Also works when everything is static. Somehow scope resolution feels better than member access to a dummy object, but that's just me being weird. +1

Answer (score 3):

The nearest thing to forward-declaring a `namespace` is to rely on the fact that they can be split up (unlike a `class` declaration), even into different translation units! Hence you can write

```
namespace funcion // [sic]
{
}
```

before `main`. Note well the braces.

Comment: It won't, however, solve OP's problem of calling a function that hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: @Quentin; No but they can forward declare that inside the otherwise so-far blank namespace if they want.

Comment: ... which removes the point of the question. Not your fault though ;)

Comment: Well,if i do like this way,i have to put every thing into the forwawrd declared namespace before `main()`,which is also annoying to me.

Comment: @bigxiao - To be blunt, you can either accept that's how you need to do things, or switch to another programming language. This is just the way C++ is today. It may change in 2.5 years when C++20 rolls out with its fancy module system, but we are still far off.

Answer (score 1):

This won't solve your problem.

You can declare the namespace earlier like this:

```
namespace function {};
int main()
{
  using namespace function;
  f1();
}
namespace function
{
  void f1() {}
}
```

but `f1` is still not declared in `main`.

How about extracting the function declarations to a header file and including it?

`somefile.h`

```
#pragma once
namespace function {
  void f1();
};
```

`somefile.cpp`

```
#include "somefile.h"

int main()
{
  using namespace function;//compiler could not find this actually;
  f1();
}

namespace function
{
  void f1() {}
}
```

---

> so I have to place everything into one .cpp file

Then just forget the `#include` and do one of the following:

a. put the declaration `namespace function { void f1(); }` above `int main()` and the definition (function body) below `int main()`

b. put the `int main()` last, so that you don't require additional declarations